# Como fazer mapeamento 1:N (um para muitos) no Dapper?

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

Estou usando o [Dapper](http://stackexchange.github.io/dapper-dot-net/) que é um micro ORM usado para mapear os objetos de acordo com as tabelas do banco de dados seguindo o modelo relacional. Sendo assim, tenho algumas dúvidas em relação ao mapeamento e a estrutura das classes.

Para ilustrar a situação criei duas classes que representa duas tabelas do meu banco de dados, as duas classes são `Cliente` e `Telefone`, segue o código:

Classe Cliente:

```
public class Cliente
{
    int IdCliente {get; set;}
    string Nome {get; set;}    
}
```

Classe Telefone:

```
public class Telefone 
{
    int IdTelefone {get; set;}
    int IdCliente {get; set;}
    string Numero {get; set;}
}
```

O relacionamento dessas duas classes deve representar um relacionamento 1:N (um para muitos), ou seja, um cliente pode ter vários números de telefones.

## Dúvidas

- A esta estrutura atual das classe esta em conformidade com Dapper
  para que ele faça o mapeamento relacional?
- Existe outras estruturas que eu possa seguir de acordo com o cenário
  acima?
- Como ficaria uma consulta com um `inner join` que obtivessem os
  seguintes campos `Nome` (Cliente) e `Numero` (Telefone)?

Comment: Acredito que você pode encontrar a resposta que procura através deste artigo escrito pelo Macoratti. http://www.macoratti.net/15/12/adn_dapper1.htm
*Não adicionei a resposta completa para contemplar o autor do artigo.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Dapper* é uma ferramenta extremamente performática por trabalhar em um nível bem próximo das interfaces do ADO. Entretanto, nenhuma interface é provida para expressar relacionamentos.

Você precisará implementar a sua própria solução, ou utilizar uma biblioteca de terceiros, como [AutoMapper](https://github.com/SlapperAutoMapper/Slapper.AutoMapper).

Assim sendo, minhas respostas seriam:

> Esta estrutura está em conformidade para que ele faça o mapeamento relacional?

Dapper não pode prover mapeamento relacional, apenas de propriedades de objetos.

> Existe outras estruturas que eu possa seguir de acordo com o cenário acima?

Não. Ou, melhor descrevendo, não há requisitos na definição esperada pelo Dapper para declarar dependências de estruturas.

> Como ficaria uma consulta com um inner join que obtivessem os seguintes campos Nome (Cliente) e Numero (Telefone)?

Você pode simplesmente implementar uma classe com estas duas propriedades para conter o resultado de uma cláusula `SQL` contendo seu `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Neste caso esta consulta com a cláusula `SQL` contendo o `INNER JOIN` vai retornar uma lista de objetos do tipo da minha classe Cliente/Telefone?

Comment: @gato exatamente - na verdade você pode até mesmo criar classes complexas, mas terá que executar métodos discretos no Dapper para cada elemento unitário ou coleção.

Answer (score 2):

Acabei de publicar um artigo sobre multi-mapping com o Dapper
[Multi-Mapping com Dapper](https://medium.com/@thiagoloureiro/dapper-multi-mapping-bb57e6e9fc76)

No meu exemplo tem fonte do Github e tudo mais, mas vou explicar aqui também.

No código abaixo estou buscando uma conta bancária com várias propriedades, tipo de conta, banco, cliente, gerente etc... e é dessa forma que eu faço o relacionamento.
Espero ter ajudado.

```
public static List<BankAccount> GetList()
{
    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT
    BA.Id, BA.Account, BA.Branch,
    U.Id, U.Name,
    A.Id, A.Street, A.City,
    C.Id, C.Name,
    BK.Id, BK.Name,
    ACT.Id, ACT.Name,
    ACC.Id, ACC.Name,
    M.Id, M.Name
    from BankAccount BA
    inner join [User] U on U.Id = BA.UserId
    inner join [Address] A on A.Id = U.AddressId
    inner join Currency C on C.Id = BA.CurrencyId
    inner join Bank BK on BK.Id = BA.BankId
    inner join AccountType ACT on ACT.Id = BA.AccountTypeId
    inner join AccountCategory ACC on ACC.Id = BA.AccountCategory
    inner join Manager M on M.Id = BA.ManagerId";

    List<BankAccount> ret;
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        ret = db.Query<BankAccount>(sqlQuery,
            new[]
            {
                typeof(BankAccount),
                typeof(User),
                typeof(Address),
                typeof(Currency),
                typeof(Bank),
                typeof(AccountType),
                typeof(AccountCategory),
                typeof(Manager)
            },
            objects =>
            {
                var bankaccount = objects[0] as BankAccount;
                var user = objects[1] as User;
                var address = objects[2] as Address;
                var currency = objects[3] as Currency;
                var bank = objects[4] as Bank;
                var accounttype = objects[5] as AccountType;
                var accountcategory = objects[6] as AccountCategory;
                var manager = objects[7] as Manager;

                bankaccount.User = user;
                bankaccount.User.Address = address;
                bankaccount.Bank = bank;
                bankaccount.Currency = currency;
                bankaccount.AccountType = accounttype;
                bankaccount.AccountCategory = accountcategory;
                bankaccount.Manager = manager;

                return bankaccount;
            }, splitOn: "Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id, Id").AsList();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira que mantém o código mais simples de entender, pois não usa mapeamento, é essa, usando `dynamic`:

```
using Dapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TesteDapper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conexao = @"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=StackOverFlow;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(conexao))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var sql = @"SELECT * 
                             FROM CLIENTE CLI
                             LEFT JOIN TELEFONE TEL 
                               ON TEL.IdCliente = CLI.IdCliente";

                dynamic resultList = conn.Query(sql);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Cliente
    {
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public List Telefones { get; set; }
    }

    public class Telefone
    {
        public int IdTelefone { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Não sou profundo conhecedor do Dapper, mas creio que não seja possível criar um relacionamento one-to-many sem implementar uma lista de telefones na classe `Cliente`.

Segue resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit:**

Adicionando um projeto teste no .Net Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/JBl8oo