# Como mapear e obter apenas uma propriedade ou campo de uma consulta?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, dapper

Estou utilizando o Dapper que tem a finalidade de [mapear propriedades de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180449/27190).

Veja um exemplo prático:

```
var servico = conexao.Query<Servico>(statement.ToSql(), new { IdServico = id }).First();
```

Ou seja, o objeto `Servico` tera todas as suas propriedades mapeadas de acordo com a tabela `Servico` do banco de dados e os dados serão populados no objeto em tempo de execução.

Entretanto, eu tenho uma dúvida em relação ao mapeamento de propriedade, que eu gostaria que fosse esclarecida.

---

## Dúvida

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível mapear e obter apenas uma propriedade ou campo de uma consulta SQL usando o Dapper? E o campo a ser obtido seria o campo `Descricao` como segue no exemplo de ilustração.

Exemplo de ilustração ilustração:

```
using (conexao = new SQLiteConnection(StringDeConexao))
{
    conexao.Open();

    var sql = "select s.Descricao from Servico s where s.Descricao = @Descricao";

    string campoDescricao = conexao.Query(sql, new { Descricao = "Descricao de teste" });    
}
```

A tentativa acima resulta no seguinte erro:

> Error CS0029
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tentando jogar o resultado de uma *query*  que é uma coleção em uma *string*, isso não funciona e nem é o que deseja. Pegue o resultado, depois pegue o campo desejado:

```
using (conexao = new SQLiteConnection(StringDeConexao)) {
    conexao.Open();
    var resultado = conexao.Query("select s.Descricao from Servico s where s.Descricao = @Descricao", new { Descricao = "Descricao de teste" });
    var campoDescricao = resultado[0].Descricao;
}
```

`Descricao` obviamente é o campo, e `[0]` está pegando a primeira linha da coleção gerada. Se tiver a possibilidade de ter mais que uma linha, precisaria fazer um laço.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/PegaDescricao.cs).

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa para obter apenas um campo em uma consulta SQL usando o Dapper é especificar o tipo dele, veja um exemplo:

```
using (conexao = new SQLiteConnection(StringConexao))
{
    conexao.Open();

    var sql = "select nome from pessoa where id = @id";

    var nome = conexao.Query<string>(sql, new { id = meuId }).FirstOrDefault();

    Writeline($"Nome: {nome}");
}
```

O retorno será uma lista enumerada `IEnumerable<string>` de tipo `string`, porem, com o método `FirstOrDefault()` obtêm-se apenas uma `string` que é o primeiro elemento da lista, e fica a critério tratar a exceção `ArgumentNullException` dele.

Fonte:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx
https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: O Gabe me baniu do chat. Não tenho como responder lá. Me adiciona no Facebook por favor.